# how to append data to the last row, from the list to asp.net grid view? so that my uploaded file will be shown latest

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My requirement is to upload a file everytime at the bottom row of the gridview and the datalist has the new attached file. Now it is showing the uploaded files randomly in the rows of the UploadedReportGrid gridview. Please help

```
private void UpdateReportList()
        {
            ICrashReportService clientUpload = new CrashReportServiceClient();
            RequestIdentifier requestIdentifier = new RequestIdentifier { RequestId = Id };

            try
            {
                CrashReportCollection data = clientUpload.GetCrashReportsByRequestId(requestIdentifier);

                List<CrashData> datalist = ConvertToCrashData(data);

                UploadedReportGrid.DataSource = datalist;
                UploadedReportGrid.DataBind();

                SetFirstItemToButtonForReport(datalist);
            }
            catch (FaultException fx)
            {
                UploadStatusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Error: " + fx.Message;
            }
        }
```

I have a list(datalist) of CrashData class which has elements(properties) like file,reportid,version,categoryid,occureddate, every time I upload a file its details are stored in the datalist which is the datasource for my grid view(UploadedReportGrid), but in the grid the latest uploaded file is not shown in the last row. the grid rows which has crash report files is not shown in the uploaded order

Comment: Add a new `CrashData` to `datalist` before binding it to the GridView.

Comment: maybe you need to set a sort order on the datalist

Comment: but there is no uploaded date propert to sort

Comment: I don't even understand what you want to happen since your question says `upload a file every time at the bottom row` which is quite vague. Are you displaying details about uploaded files in your gridview and if yes, then what do you want to display in last row?

Comment: I have a list(datalist) of CrashData class which has elements(properties) like file,reportid,version,categoryid,occureddate, every time I upload a file its details are stored in the datalist which is the datasource for my grid view(UploadedReportGrid), but in the grid the latest uploaded file is not shown in the last row. the grid rows which has crash report files is not shown in the uploaded order

Comment: i want the gridview sorted by the order I upload the files

Comment: @Sunil Am I clear now? Pls suggest

Comment: It is clear now.  You need to mention these things in your original question,  so others can quickly understand your scenario and help you.

Comment: @VDWWD could you please elaborate, I did nt get your point

Answer (score 1):

In your situation,  all you need to do is sort the data list on occurreddate before setting data source of gridview.

Use the code snippet given below, where you are setting data source of gridview. Make sure you use `x.OcurredDate` with proper case since class member names are case sensitive. The LINQ extension method `OrderBy` will order by ascending order of the property `OccurredDate`.

```
UploadedReportGrid.DataSource = datalist.OrderBy(x => x.OcurredDate).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you sunil, but my task is not to order by the OccuredDate, I need to orderby uploaded order. which is challenging. there is no property called UploadedDate

Comment: Then look at the properties available for class CrashData,  and if there is a datetime property for upload,  then just use that in code I have in my answer.

Comment: Also,  what does OccurredDate represent?

Comment: there is no datetime property which takes the uploaded time , do i need to add in the db or do i need to add in the xml file? to store all the Uploaded Dates, well occured date is nothing but the crash occured date, i want to upload the crashes in the UploadedReportGrid in an uploaded order

Comment: but even if I add a column in db I cannot fetch the uploaded dates for already existing crash files

Comment: Are you getting the data from web service? If yes,  then look at the web service method and modify it so the uploaded date is retrieved and then a property called UploadedDate in CrashData  class is set in web service code.   You may need to add this new property to CrashData class if its not already there.

Comment: getting data from the database which is fetched by the service, but if there are already uploaded files in the grid, how should I get the date.